# Why is Visual Studio 2019 debugger not showing all the information it used to when running an ASP.Net Core web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

So, the debugger window at the bottom is not logging all the information it used to, I can't remember when that changed exactly but I think it happened after I deployed the app to Azure. I made sure that I'm running it in development environment (which was changed to build upon deployment), but I still get limited information. For instance, I don't get my Debug.WriteLine information and much more. I tried comparing all the settings to the ones I have in my project that's logging all the information I need and I still can't figure it out. Here are their different outputs:

Project that works on starting app.

```
Verbose logs are written to:
C:\Users\KW\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-chrome-debug.txt
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Us
ers\KW\Desktop\asp.net\Warehousely\Warehousely\Warehousely\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Warehousely.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

Broken project on starting app.

```
Verbose logs are written to:
C:\Users\KW\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-chrome-debug.txt
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\AcLayers.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'.
```

Project that works upon request.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44388/  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executing endpoint 'Warehousely.Controllers.HomeController.Index (Warehousely)'
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Home", page = "", area = ""}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Index() on controller Warehousely.Controllers.HomeController (Warehousely).
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor: Information: Executing ViewResult, running view Index.
```

Broken project upon request.

```
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\KW\Desktop\asp.net\LandingPage\LandingPage\LandingPage\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\KW\Desktop\asp.net\LandingPage\LandingPage\LandingPage\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\KW\Desktop\asp.net\LandingPage\LandingPage\LandingPage\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\KW\Desktop\asp.net\LandingPage\LandingPage\LandingPage\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions.dll'.
```

Here are some things I noticed.

1. The project that is NOT logging properly doesn't show anything coming from "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics".
2. The project that is NOT logging properly logs everything with the 'iisexpress.exe' prefix.

The appsettings.json for both is:

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
},
```

In properties in Environmental variables:

```
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
```

Comment: Any custom setup of logging in the startup/program.cs/addlogging/loggeroptions? Filters etc can be set there too

Comment: @CaiusJard No, everything is standard and the same as the working project, tho I don't know where to find addlogging and loggeroptions.